# Changing Unicode string in to int in python

Tags: python, unicode, int

How can I parse a Unicode string to int in python 2.7?
I tried:

```
a= int(input)
```

but couldn't succeed.

Comment: What do you expect the int to map to? The byte value of the character? The codepoint of the glyph? Is it one glyph? One codepoint? An entire string?

Comment: please be specific about input...

Comment: Is `input` the built-in?  If so, then you are going to need to call it:  `a= int(input())`

Comment: "but couldn't succeed" tells us **nothing**. Did you get an exception? Show that, including the traceback. Did you get an unexpected result? Show the result, what you would have expected in its place, and why. Did something else strange happen? Describe it so we don't need crystal balls to help you. In short: What makes you say it failed?

Answer (score 2):

input() is a built in function in python. It returns a string by default. You can use external type casting to convert string into any other data type.

```
d = input('Enter a number')
# d will have a string value

e = int(d)
# e is now an integer value

print e * 10

a = input('Enter your name')
# a will have a string value

c = a + "is an awesome person"
# string concatination
```

Comment: you should probably mention that this will produce errors if the user does not do what he is supposed to. Moreover, input is only python 3k ;-)

Comment: @Ant - [`input()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) in Py2 is the equivalent of `exec(raw_input())` - it reads a string and executes it as Python code. Most people seem to agree that this is almost always a bad idea without careful sanitization first...

Comment: yes, i know.. I didn even consider input in py2 cause i know it's  bad idea, i was referring to the fact that the code shown only works in python 3k (where input works as raw_input), whereas in python 2 you have to use raw_input to achieve the same behaviour

Answer (score 1):

You can use a try-except loop to cast the input as an int. If an incorrect value is entered, and exception will be thrown and will re-prompt the user for the input.

```
while True:
     try:
          number = int(input("Enter and integer."))
     except:
          print("An integer is a WHOLE NUMBER, genius.")
     else:
          break

print(number + 10)
```

Comment: Why not catch for a `ValueError`?  Using just a naked `except` is not a good coding practice.